# How to use a data from time series (e.g.) in ode function?

Tags: matlab, struct, time-series, double, ode

i want to use data from another mat file which contains a timeseries, below is a simplified example:

```
1. tspan = [0 5];
2. y0 = 0;
3. tQ = linspace(0,5,25);
4. Qg = load('GasFlowRate_T.mat', 'Qg');
5.
6. [t y] = ode45(@(t,y) f(t,y,tQ,Qg),tspan,y0);
7. plot(t,y)
8.
9.    function dydt = f(t,y,tQ,Qg)
10.        Qg = interp1(tQ, Qg, t);
11.        dydt = Qg*t;
12.   end
```

and i will get the error:

```
Error using interp1>reshapeValuesV (line 439)
Values V must be of type double or single.
Error in interp1>reshapeAndSortXandV (line 419)
[V,orig_size_v] = reshapeValuesV(V);
Error in interp1 (line 93)
    [X,V,orig_size_v] = reshapeAndSortXandV(varargin{1},varargin{2});
```

but i also couldn't convert from struct to double, how could i exactly to use the data from timeseries?

Comment: In principle this is correct. What is `Qg`, what structure does it have, what does a typical entry, for instance `Qg(1)` or `Qg(1,:)`, look like?

Comment: I have tried to save the data in array, and then i can get the value using the way you are also mentioned. Though thank you a lot to answer it. @LutzLehmann